# Typescript definitions for embedded interpreter classes

Tags: typescript, spidermonkey

I am using a proprietary piece of software that uses spidermonkey for scripting interaction.  I am interested in using typescript instead of JavaScript for writing those scripts.  Is there a way to run JavaScript code to extract the interfaces already defined in the JavaScript scripting environment (e.g. custom classes through the C++ interface)?  Is there even a way to define typescript classes that are actually defined through other means (i.e. C++ access to the interpreter)?

I'm just starting to look into typescript and am not very experienced with using JavaScript, so forgive me if this question is a bit muddled.